# Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 environment for SharePoint 2010 development?

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio

I was wondering if it is possible to install Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (development) environment for SharePoint 2010 development? Do I need to [install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/02/microsoft-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-with-compatibility-support-for-visual-studio-2012-and-windows-8.aspx) in order to make it compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2?

Is Visual studio compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2 or do I need to install Visual Studio 2012?

I'm under the impression that [Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is only supported until Windows Server 2008 R2. Is there anyone here that can tell me if this is possible and what to look out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can install and  develop apps with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

http://nakedalm.com/installing-visual-studio-2010-on-windows-8/

https://superuser.com/questions/634400/windows-server-2012-sql-server-2012-and-net-framework-4-0

Comment: I can confirm that installing Visual Studio 2010 together with Visual Studio Service Pack 1 is possible. A server reboot is required after the installation of Visual Studio.